# Optimising a julia one-liner to make it as fast as python

Tags: python, julia

I have written a simple one-liner in julia to solve a little maths problem: find a two digit number, A and a three digit number B such that their product, A x B is a five digit numbers and every digit from 0 to 9 appears exactly once among the numbers A, B and A x B. For example,

```
54 x 297 = 16,038
```

Here is my julia code which finds all the possible solutions:

```
println(filter(l -> length(unique(reduce(vcat, (map(digits, l))))) == 10, [[x, y, x*y] for x in Range(10:99), y in Range(100:999)]))
```

It solves the problem but then I tried in python and came up with this:

```
print filter(lambda y: len(set(''.join([str(x) for x in y])))==10, [[x, y, x*y] for x in range(10, 99) for y in range(100, 999)])
```

Timing them both, I was surprised to find that the python code ran more than twice as fast as the julia code. Any suggestions for a faster approach for the julia code (preferably keeping it to a one-liner)?

*Aside: I know I can improve both with a quick tweak of the ranges to* `range(12, 98)` *and* `range(102, 987)`.

*Update*

Moving beyond one-liners, I've taken the advice that loops can be faster than lists, so I compared the following alternatives:

**Julia**

```
ans = Array{Tuple{Int32, Int32, Int32}}(0)
for x in 12:98 
  for y in 102:987
    if length(unique(digits(x+y*100+x*y*100_000)))==10 push!(ans, (x, y, x*y) end
  end
end
println(ans)
```

**Python**

```
ans = []
for x in range(12,98): 
  for y in range(102,987):
    if len(set(str(x+y*100+x*y*100000)))==10:
      ans.append((x, y, x*y))
print ans
```

The python code runs much faster (even if I change the code for both to simply print out the results in the loop rather than collect them in a list). I was expecting better performance from julia.

Also, in case you are interested, the complete list of solutions is

```
39 x 402 = 15,678
27 x 594 = 16,038
54 x 297 = 16,038
36 x 495 = 17,820
45 x 396 = 17,820
52 x 367 = 19,084
78 x 345 = 26,910
46 x 715 = 32,890
63 x 927 = 58,401
```

Comment: I was timing these with `time` on the command line. Using `@time` in julia and `timeit` in python suggests that the python code is only about 65% faster rather than more than double, but that's still a significant difference.

Comment: just replace `[x,y,x*y]` to `(x,y,x*y)` can get a 30% improvement. You can also replace `Range(10:99)` with `10:99` to shorten your code.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting that changing to tuples rather than lists gives a significant improvement for julia but is negligible for python.

Comment: Are you timing this in global scope? Try putting everything inside a function `f()`. Run the function once, then do `@time f()`. This is the correct way to do a simple benchmark in Julia.

Comment: Why are you using a `set` in Python but not a `Set` in Julia? Did you try?

Comment: Also, `ans` is not a good variable name in Julia, since it is used to refer to the previous result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@simd for x in 10:99 for y in 100:999 length(unique(digits(x+y*100+x*y*100_000)))==10 && println(x,'*',y,'=',x*y) end end`

In my computer this code is about 3x the speed of the origin one. (0.223902 seconds vs 0.680781 seconds)

The key is to ["avoid unnecessary arrays"](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/performance-tips/#tweaks). Use `for` loops or tuple when possible

Comment: Nice solution, I have one question... what's the purpose of @simd on this example and how do you know when to use it?

Comment: @Esteban It is from [julia doc](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/performance-tips/#performance-annotations), but to be honest it makes little enhancement in this example

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - defintely faster. Interestingly, I also modified the python code in a similar to use loops rather than arrays and the result is significantly faster than the julia code. Admittedly, the whitespace formatting requirement means that the python code is four lines not one.